# How to increase data insert time in MySQL with Spring JPA? And what is the best way to solve this problem?

Tags: java, mysql, spring, jpa

People, hello everyone. We have Spring boot under the hood. It is necessary to periodically insert 1k records into the MySQL database, first checking for the presence of these, in order to avoid duplicates. The problem is slow insertion, and periodic OutOfMemoryException. Host = 1GB of RAM, 1 core.
What I did:

1. Tried to load, first pulling one record at a time, and if there is none, then adding it to ArrayList , then this collection, saving it with the standard Spring JPA method - saveAll(); Got the above error.
2. Started splitting by 10k and also loading via saveAll();
   The error with memory periodically dropped out. Googled, remembered that hibernate caches all saved records. Now I made a custom repository, where I injected the EntityManager, and wrote the saveAll method, in which, while walking through the collection, I do em.persist(MyObject). After 10k iterations, I do em.flush: em.clear();

Inserting data is very slow, but the memory error seems to have disappeared...

The question is, how is this problem solved?

Code my custom repo

```
    private EntityManager entityManager;

    @Override
    public void saveList(List<Data> list) {
        int batchSize = 50;
        int i = 0;
        for (Data data : list) {
            i++;
            entityManager.persist(data);
            if (i % batchSize == 0) {
                entityManager.flush();
                entityManager.clear();
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Reduce the batch size (use something like 50/100 not 10K), enable batch statements on both hibernate **and** mysql driver. And don't read the data all in a list but rather process/read and write directly (you might even want to leverage Spring Batch here but not sure how you are reading or need to rpocess the data).

Comment: I tried to enable batch data via in settings
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.order_inserts=true
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.order_updates=true
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.jdbc.batch_size=50
but in logs all the same there were single inserts. what does it mean to process and read?

Comment: MySQL is different, you need to enable it on the driver level as well (hibernate will log still single elements, however the driver will convert them to a single one, but you have to enable it!), regarding the batch size you need to decrease the batch size in your code as well. And please don't add additional config/code/etc. as comments as those are totally unreadable.